# How to use apply() to fill up a column from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I created the following function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn

def split_and_recombine(x):
    #print(type(x.tolist()))
    arr = x.tolist()[0].split('.')
    wn = arr[1][1:]
    sd = f'{arr[3]}-{arr[2]}-{wn}'
    #print(sd)
    return sd
```

And I passed it through the following statement:

```
df[df['ProductID'].isnull()].apply(split_and_recombine(df.ItemCode))
```

However I got an error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '178063-1-10'

What I am trying to obtain is that `df['ProductID']` gets filled with the result of applying the function, for every row passed through it.

```
ProductID   ItemCode
Nan         BJ.A10.5.16543
17281-5-00  BF.F00.5.17281
```

Desired output:

```
ProductID   ItemCode
16543-5-10  BJ.A10.5.16543
17281-5-00  BF.F00.5.17281
```

Basically for every row in a dataset of 1.4 million records where the ProductID is Nan (1640 of them) and I want to have these filled up with the calculated value of the column ItemCode using the function I wrote.

Comment: can you add all of your code please.

Comment: Which extra code would you need, because this is basically it?

Comment: whats your import look like?

Comment: what did you name your script?

Comment: I updated my question with the import statement

Comment: Provide sample data and the desired output please.

Comment: I am running it in a jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how i've done it:

```
def split_and_recombine(row):
    arr = row['ItemCode'].split('.')
    wn = arr[1][1:]
    return f'{arr[3]}-{arr[2]}-{wn}'

df['ItemCode'] = df['ItemCode'].astype('str')
df.loc[df['ProductID'].isnull(), 'ProductID'] = df[df['ProductID'].isnull()].apply(split_and_recombine, axis=1)

print(df)
ProductID        ItemCode
0  16543-5-10  BJ.A10.5.16543
1  17281-5-00  BF.F00.5.17281
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting .productID before .apply

So far it is not clear its applying to that column.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now it gives the following error `AttributeError: '178063-1-10' is not a valid function for 'Series' object`.

Comment: In your split and combine function, arr = x.split(‘.’)

Comment: Also my bet , shouldnt put productID in front of apply, put ItemCode in front of apply

Comment: When I take out the comments in front of the print statements I noticed in the function that I'm getting the correct result for the passed in Series. It's when the function returned to the apply function that it fails.

Comment: You meant with the suggestions I commented ? I am not sure if you meant errors or wrong results